# Get index by name with the ElasticSearch ruby gem

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

My Model:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
end
```

When I ask if the index exists, I get `true`:

```
Package.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.exists(index: "packages")
=> true
```

But when I do:

```
Package.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.get(index: "packages")
```

I get this error:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] No handler found for uri [/packages] and method [GET]
```

I already have some documents indexed, and I can do a search, so what's wrong with the line above?

ps: here's the doc: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch/API/Indices/Actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the way you've configured your elasticsearch client in your initializer. If you're using the typhoeus adapter, see this discussion: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/issues/316

Something that might also be helpful is debugging how things are actually indexed / mapped via their marvel plugin http://localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel/sense/index.html?

GET _cat/indices
GET packages/_mapping

Comment: I got it... just checked the client:  `Mission.__elasticsearch__.client`. And I see hosts like `...4238643.us-east-1.bonsai.io`! So it means by default it uses their remove service bonsai.io! Thanks

Comment: It's not actually by default btw, I had an initializer that was setting the new host...